# Naming of a pointer to single object/instance of a data type

Tags: c, types, syntax, terminology

*The prelude...*

Where I work, people say I have the wrong terminology or invent my own. My boss says the right terminology is very important when working in a team.

*The question*

In C, what is the right term to use when we are referring to a pointer to any data type? For example I want to create macro functions of a `send()` function like this:

```
size_t send_stub (socket, void* , size_t);

#define send_str(sock, str) send_stub(sock, str, strlen(str))
```

then it will follow to create such a macro for data types with known size like pointers, byte, int16, int32, int64, arrays, structures, enums, but I would like to create a single macro function for all of them. What would it be called?

```
#define send_?(sock, ?) send_stub(sock, ?, sizeof(?))
```

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "macro function"?

Comment: I would argue that you shouldn't use function-like macros at all, and always use `send_stub` directly at all times. That makes it more clear what you do. Macros generally tend to make code harder to read and understand.

Comment: Regarding the naming, why not call it `send_data`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I wouldn't say this is very clear. Data can refer to so many things.

Comment: @Yunnosch what an irony haha. Isn't a macro function the name of a macro as such #define x(y)

Comment: All pointers only point to a single object/instance. So I think the correct name would be a "pointer".

Comment: @Edenia Yet, that's what you want, one name to refer many things. Can you see the irony now? :)

Comment: @Yunnosch A pointer can also point to a beginning of string or a buffer though.

Comment: I would call that a parameterized macro. Among other reasons it prevents people from misunderstanding you for talking about a function.

Comment: @Yunnosch Good point.

Comment: Ironic indeed. A macro is not a function. The correct term is *function-like macro*. It only looks the same, but the two concepts are very far apart.

Comment: A macro which attempts to do the job of a function I would call a "bad idea". Now THAT is irony, on the edge to sarcasm.

Comment: @Yunnosch It is a standard practice in GNU-like products. Also a macro implies something that saves time and does something automatically, so it is at least not reinventing the wheel or so to say

Comment: @SouravGhosh haha yes. Well, data is a bit too broader than something that groups a pointer to a single instance of data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can take our lead from the C standard itself here. I'll be quoting n1570, the C11 standard draft.

> **3. Terms, definitions, and symbols**
>
> [3.15](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15) **object**
>   1 region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values
>   2 NOTE When referenced, an object may be interpreted as having a particular type; see 6.3.2.1.

Seems to be right up your alley. If you assume the token provided as argument to the macro is an expression that evaluates to a pointer which points at a single object, then `send_object` seems appropriate.

```
#define send_object(sock, obj_ptr) send_stub(sock, (obj_ptr), sizeof *(obj_ptr))
```

If we also assume the pointer is to a complete object type, then `sizeof *(obj_ptr)` is the size of that object.

Comment: I also like that object and string are words of the same lengths, aligns well when defined under the string macro haha. (If you thought that I am a fan of readability you are right).